# Document modified asterisk * not removed when aspx page modified and saved-in visual studio 2012

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2012

This was a known issue in visual studio 2012:
https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/763073/document-modified-asterisk-not-removed-when-aspx-page-modified-and-saved
It is marked as closed (fixed in VS 2013) but I experience it now in VS 2013 Update 4 (was also an issue in Update 3).

Does anyone experience the same? I didn't find Microsoft Connect issue for this.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue with Visual Studio 2015 Update 3.  If I am working in the ASPX file and modify it, the modified asterisk will not be removed when pressing Ctrl+S, Ctrl+Shift+S, File>Save or File>Save All.  The file saves, but the modified indicator is still displayed.

I have found that if I then go to the ASPX.CS file, make a change and save it that I can then go back to the ASPX file and save it using any of the above mentioned ways and the modified asterisk will be removed.

I haven't been able to find anything about this issue and VS 2015.  I currently am working on two separate projects in VS 2015, both are Web Forms projects.  One project was first created when there was no updates to VS 2015.  This project has this issue.  The other project was created after Update 3 was installed and it does not have this issue.